# Is segmentation fault handler thread-safe?

Tags: linux, multithreading, segmentation-fault

When segmentation fault occurs on Linux within multithreaded application and handler is called, are all other threads instantly stopped before handler is called?
So, is it appropriate to rely on fact that no any parralel code will execute during segmentation fault handling?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you test in a simple program? Start two threads, one with own SIGSEGV handler. SIGSEGV that thread and put it to sleep from inside the handler. First thread runs in an infinite loop printing something. Then you answer your question yourself. I dont know it myself and I am interested to learn

Comment: That's simple, really, but I am trying to avoid such decisions, if I'll run and test the behaviour, it will be proved only for specific harware/software version (gcc, libc, linux distro, debug/release and so on...). But targeted software is run on multiple platforms.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`signal(7)`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/signal) manual page:

> A signal may be generated (and thus pending) for a process as a whole (e.g., when sent using kill(2)) or for a specific thread (e.g., certain signals, such as SIGSEGV and SIGFPE, generated as a consequence of executing a specific machine-language instruction are thread directed, as are signals targeted at a specific thread using pthread_kill(3)). A process-directed signal may be delivered to any one of the threads that does not currently have the signal blocked. If more than one of the threads has the signal unblocked, then the kernel chooses an arbitrary thread to which to deliver the signal.

This paragraph says that certain signals, like `SIGSEGV`, are thread specific. Which should answer your question.

Comment: I cannot see a direct answer on this paragraph: it says that SIGSEGV will be targeted at a specific thread but nothing sayd about a destiny of other threads.

Comment: @Slav To be honest, if you get a segmentation fault it's not very likely that you can continue after it anyway. Sooner of later the error will cascade and the whole process will die anyway. Trapping `SIGSEGV` is only useful to provide extra logging before aborting the process, unless the error is _in_ the logging code in which case it will still die horribly.

Comment: I think so too and am implementing some "safe-before-die" tasks within seg-fault-handler. Here and there I face some errors within multiple libraries I use and want not to miss any cashed data within server, but it won't be useful if server will keep modifying data right when I'll be saving it within seg-fault-handler.